# I cant make this class enumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I  have a table in the db named Personel and the field names are:
Id,Name,LastName,Salary and Position.I have created a class which extends `DataContext`then creates columns with properties .Then I have tried itarate through in this class .But I am getting this exception below. Fields names and values are correct I have no idea what is this error

> Specified cast is not valid.

this is my class

```
  public  class PersonelDbContext:DataContext
    {
      public Table<Personel> Personel;
      public PersonelDbContext()
          : base("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Project;User Id=sa;Password=1")
      {


      }

    }
[Table(Name="Personel")]
    public class Personel {
    private int _id;

    private string _name;


    private string _lastname;


    private int _salary;


    private string _position;



    [Column(Name="Id",Storage="_id",DbType="Int not null",IsPrimaryKey=true,IsDbGenerated=true)]

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    [Column (Name="Name",Storage="_name",DbType="Int not null identity")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    [Column(Name="LastName",Storage="_lastname",DbType="Nvarchar not null")]
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set { _lastname = value; }
    }

     [Column(Name="Salary",Storage="_salary",DbType="Int not null")]
    public int Salary
    {
        get { return _salary; }
        set { _salary = value; }
    }

       [Column(Name="Position",Storage="_position",DbType="Nvarchar not null")]
     public string Position
     {
         get { return _position; }
         set { _position = value; }
     }
   }
//}

  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PersonelDbContext dbcontext = new PersonelDbContext();
            var query = from c in dbcontext.Personel select c;

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id:", item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Id:", item.Lastname);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Column (Name="Name",Storage="_name",DbType="Int not null identity")]
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

Look hard. What is the dbtype? Now what *should* it be? I'm guessing `nvarchar(200) not null` or something similar.

Also: your `Console.WriteLine` lines won't work; you might mean one of:

```
Console.WriteLine("Id:" + item.Name);
```

or:

```
Console.WriteLine("Id:{0}", item.Name);
```

Comment: My fault Marc thank you so much